# Convert (ArrayLists) in java android

Tags: java, android

If I have `Arraylist<Integer>` how can I do convert it to `ArrayList<String>`

```
final ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = 
    new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(19,85,955,9,2,62,96,2,6,26,2,26,2));
```

the Toast did not print any think on the Screen

```
ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.arraylistv);
     final ArrayList<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(19,85,955,9,2,62,96,2,6,26,2,26,2));
    final ArrayAdapter< Integer> arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"your num is  "+arrayList,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's already an `ArrayList`?

Comment: What do you mean? As flakes said it is already an ArrayList? How do you convert an int to an int?

Comment: Do you mean how to populate a `List` with values using `asList`? Then you miss the static import `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: target array contains String and not Integer? you maybe could try something like that : 'listInt.stream.map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())'

Comment: what have you tried so far ? where is your code ? switching from Integer to String is very well documented all over the internet, did you search into the java doc or java online courses ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use streams to easily convert type of a `List`, like this:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(19,85,955,9,2,62,96,2,6,26,2,26,2);
List<String> result = input.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case, we're using `map` to convert each element using `String::valueOf` - which basically is a function that converts the input into a string.  You can replace this with any other function to convert the input type to other types.

Comment: If you really need to to be an `ArrayList` you can also do `input.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))`